# is it a cardinal rule of microservices that a single database table should only be represented by a single microservice?

Tags: microservices

Is it a cardinal rule of microservices that a single database table should only be represented by a single microservice?  I was asked that in an interview.  My first reaction was that it should only be 1 to 1.  But then I think I was overthinking it, thinking that maybe there are some edge case scenarios where that may be acceptable.

So is it a cardinal rule of microservices that a single database table should always be represented by a single microservice?  Or are there some edge case scenarios where that may be acceptable?  If it's a cardinal rule then is there any type of standard acronym that includes that principal?  For example, relational databases have the ACID principals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a cardinal rule. But, it is the most effective way to manage data. Design patterns are not set in stone. You may choose to handle things differently.
But, each microservice should be independent. This is why we use the microservices architecture. But, say you update a table using multiple microservices, then they (the services) become interdependent. Loose coupling no longer exists. The services will impact each other any time a change takes place.

This is why, you may want to follow the following paradigms:

1. Private-tables-per-service – each service owns a set of tables that
   must only be accessed by that service.
2. Schema-per-service – each service has a database schema that’s
   private to that service
3. Database-server-per-service – each service has it’s own database
   server.

Refer to the data management section here for more: https://microservices.io/patterns/

Answer (score 0):

It is not just a separate database for individual microservices, there are other factors that need to consider while developing microservices like  codebase, config, log etc.

Please refer to below link which explains in detail.

https://12factor.net/